# Where is the pypy package in installed pypy-c

Tags: python, macports, pypy

I have pypy-c installed with macports (latest version : pypy @1.4.1). I run pypy-c and try to import pypy

```
$ pypy-c
>>>> import pypy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pypy
>>>> from pypy import translator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pypy
```

How do I import the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to import pypy for?

There's no pypy module in the binary distribution, but there's one in the [source checkout](http://pypy.org/download.html#translate).

Comment: Well, the macports is actually installed from source, as in it builds it afresh on your computer when you install it. I am trying to import pypy for two reasons.

  1. Mainly: To install other packages, the patch for this ticket : https://codespeak.net/issue/pypy-dev/issue662 uses pypy.
  2. I want to experiment with rpython to build my own executables, though this is not that important.

Comment: For 1, you could build it yourself with the patch applied (using the macports source or, more likely to work, a fresh checkout). For both cases, you need a source tree to get at what you want.

Comment: But the patch applied will execute from the binary pypy-c, after pypy is built. Even with pypy-c built from source import pypy doesn't work.

Comment: That is correct AFAIK. Maybe it's possible to test it in untranslated PyPy using py.py with the patch applied, join IRC for details.